# Wordpress shortcodes not working in dynamic loading content

Tags: ajax, wordpress, shortcode

I'm trying to dynamically load content of posts which have [gallery] shortcodes inside their content. But ajax requests don't have access neither to do_shortcode nor to gallery callback function (gallery_shortcode).

This is how I request content:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    loading = false;
    $('#menu_left').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!loading) {
            loading = true;
            var data = {
                action: 'glevouir_ajax_load',
                nonce: glevouirajaxload.nonce,
                pageid: $(this).parent().attr("id")
            };
            $.post(glevouirajaxload.url, data, function (res) {
                if (res.success) {
                    $("#content").slideUp("fast", function () {
                        $("#content").html(res.data);
                        $(this).slideDown("fast", function () {
                            // Animation complete.
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
            loading = false;
        }
    });
});
```

And these are my wordpress function to parse these requests:

```
function glevouir_scripts()
{
    $args = array(
        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('cleavir-ajax-load-nonce'),
        'url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
    );

    wp_enqueue_script('glevouir-ajax-load', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-load.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_localize_script('glevouir-ajax-load', 'glevouirajaxload', $args);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'glevouir_scripts');

function glevouir_ajax_load()
{

    $page_id = esc_attr($_POST['pageid']);

    ob_start();

    if ( function_exists( 'do_shortcode ' ) )  {
        echo "do_shortcode exists";
        if(is_object($post_obj))
            echo do_shortcode($post_obj->post_content);
    } else {
        echo "do_shortcode doesn't exist";  // this gets echoed
    }


    $attr = array(
        "link" => "file",
        "columns" => 4,
        "ids" => "98,97,96"
    );

    if ( function_exists( 'gallery_shortcode ' ) )  {
        echo "gallery_shortcode exists";
        echo gallery_shortcode($attr);
    } else {
        echo "gallery_shortcode doesn't exist";  // this gets echoed
    }

    $data = ob_get_clean();

    wp_send_json_success($data);
    wp_die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_glevouir_ajax_load', 'glevouir_ajax_load');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_glevouir_ajax_load', 'glevouir_ajax_load');
```

I don't have access neither to do_shortcode nor to gallery_shortcode. What can be possible workaround here?

Comment: `wp_ajax_glevouir_ajax_load` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_glevouir_ajax_load` seem to be custom actions. Where do they get invoked? Maybe these could be called at a later position to make sure `do_shortcode` is defined.

Comment: `add_action('wp_ajax_glevouir_ajax_load', 'glevouir_ajax_load'); add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_glevouir_ajax_load', 'glevouir_ajax_load');` <- there. By passing `action: 'glevouir_ajax_load'`, in ajax request Wordpress automatically invokes these functions. And yes, there are not defined there but I cannot find any possible solution. Because admin-ajax doesn't use frontend functions like do_shortcode etc.

Comment: I haven't worked with ajax calls yet, so I didn't get that. There is a [similar question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53309/why-might-a-plugins-do-shortcode-not-work-in-an-ajax-request) to yours. Check the accepted answer, it suggests not to use admin-ajax but handle it yourself. Maybe that will fit your needs.

Comment: use `echo apply_filters('the_content', '[gallery]');` instead